# Unwanted "accept incoming network connections" when debugging in vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a new Typescript file which is setup VERY similarly to another that I'd just finished (including the same `launch.json`). In the previous I could run the debugger with the "Current TS Test File" configuration and it just ran. Now with the new file it always pops up a dialog box like below:

[image: dialog box]

Actually I have gone back to the old file and it too is now popping up the dialog box. Is this possible due to moving to **vs-code** `1.15.0`? Is there any way to configure it to avoid this?

---

Here is the `launch.json` that I'm executing:

```
{
    "name": "Current TS Test File",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
    "args": [
      "--no-timeouts",
      "--compilers",
      "ts:ts-node/register",
      "${relativeFile}"
    ],

    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
},
```

Comment: Remote debugging must be enabled somewhere. Have a look through the settings.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I looked at params in the `launch.json` and also in the user settings and found nothing that jumped out as a setting that would prevent this.

Comment: I had thought that by setting the protocol to "inspector" that that had removed this dialog box in the past but apparently not.

Comment: Does it appear when you invoke the same command manually through a terminal? Do you have a setting in "Firewall" that would impact this?

Comment: it seems there are a lot of regressions in debugging functionality in 1.15.0. is anyone else hitting this?

Answer (score 2):

0- Find the path to the Typescript simulator

1- Copy this script and save it to a new file with a .sh extension

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to disable an app from showing the "Do you want the application xxxx to accept incoming network connections?" pop-up every time the app is run

echo "> Enter password to temporarily shut firewall off"
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate off

echo "> Add a firewall exception"
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add [path to Typescript simulator]

echo "> Re-enable firewall"
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate on

exit 0
```

2- Replace "[path to Typescript simulator]" with the actual path to the Typescript simulator.

3- You’ll need to change the permissions on the file so you can execute the script, otherwise you’ll get a “Permission denied” message if you try. You’ll only need to do this once. In Terminal, run the command:

```
chmod u+x [the path to your new script file.sh]
```

This grants you the user (u) execution permission (x) on this script file.

4- Then just drag the file into terminal and hit enter to run it. You’ll be prompted to enter your system password for sudo access.

Firewall exceptions will be reset whenever you restart your Mac, so put this script in a handy place because you’ll need to run it again.

I was looking for a similar solution today and stumbled onto this page with some helpful info:
https://tomsoderling.github.io/Disable-iOS-simulator-connections-popup/

Alternatively, this might work, but I haven't tried it:
https://wpguru.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-kill-the-accept-incoming-connections-dialogue-on-your-mac-forever/

Comment: Thank you, [the second link](https://wpguru.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-kill-the-accept-incoming-connections-dialogue-on-your-mac-forever/) really did it for me and is applicable to all apps missing or having a wrong digital signature.